# How to prevent app from installing every time i run an test in appium using python?

Tags: android, python, appium

When i run an test , the app is installed fresh every time i call up an new test case, i want the test to run on an installed app, how can i do it ?? 
or at least prevent the app from reinstalling freshly every time an test is run using appium?

I find it difficult because app has welcome screen of 8 pages, every time app is re-installed have to write code for swiping through welcome screens and welcome message. 
Here is my code

```
import os

from time import sleep


import unittest

from appium import webdriver


# Returns absolute path relative to this file and not cwd
    PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p))
class SimpleAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
#Specify platform below(Android, iOS)
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
#Specify OS version(Settings->About phone -> android version)
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4.4'
#Obtain the Device name from Adb[For Android](Terminal Command: "adb devices")
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'TA93304QZD'
#Specify the path to Application
        desired_caps['app'] = PATH('Media Drive-com.sandisk.scotti-55-v2.0.3.apk')

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
        # end the session
    self.driver.quit()

    def test_images_copy(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        for i in range(0,4):
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Next").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Close").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("OK").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Photo").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/btn_Switch_Local").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Name").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimpleAndroidTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The --no-reset option for appium should help

Comment: you just start appium with --no-reset option

Answer (score 6):

You can also add noReset to the caps:

```
desired_caps['noReset'] = True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also install the app on your device manually and instead of launching Appium with desired_caps['app'] you can just pass the package name and first activity, as such:

```
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.acme.test'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'MyFirstActivity'
```